# How to display image in webview android?

Tags: android

I am working on android. I am trying to display the page data in webview. i.e actually i am getting the data from php webservice. The result of that php webservice is 
a document with images and text.(If we right click on that page and view page source it is all the html data). But now what I am doing is I am setting the php link to the webview. So now, it is display fine in webview (same as how it is displaying in webpage). But now the document contains some images which are displaying in website but those images are not displaying in webview. What should I do now? Please help me in this regard.

Code:

```
WebView webview;
WebSettings settings;
link = "http://.............../page.php?test=123&test1=345"

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

            webview.loadUrl(link);
```

[image]

Comment: Display one image or multiples?

Comment: post screen shot as you want

Comment: Are you getting web page in response or only getting data in response and displaying that data in WebView?

Comment: Have you tried to open it in the desktop browser? Maybe URL's of the image are incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

please add this line,

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);